# UIWebView and Google Maps

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to get the current location in my UIWebView, but it won't work. I tried this code:

```
NSString *website = @"http://www.domain/";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:website];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webpage loadRequest:request];
```

what im looking for is to integrate the current location with my UIwebview
Can anyone tell me how to get the current location?

Comment: your question is not clear , can you explain  more

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i just add it

Comment: how it possible bro, what is the purpose u tried this

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik what im try to do is get the user current location so that i can let him select the location near him to submit value, as now i just keep it without location and this is bad.

Comment: why you are not prepare the `CoreLocation frame work ` for fetch user Location

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik do you have link to show how i can fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step-1**

Add these two properties in info.plist

`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and below property

[image]

**Step-2**

on your view controller call delegate method

```
  #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *longitude;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *latitude;
```

**Step-3**

```
on your Implementation File on your `viewDidLoad`

   - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    }
```

**Step-4**

```
 -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"There was an error retrieving your location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[errorAlert show];
NSLog(@"Error: %@",error.description);
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
  {
CLLocation *crnLoc = [locations lastObject];
latitude= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.latitude];
longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.longitude];


}
```

for sample see [this](http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/objective-c/getting-the-users-location-using-corelocation/)  and [this](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/)

Comment: if you need the support I will help you